# compare an array of string with another array of strings in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, compare, logic

I want to compare an array of string with another array of strings; if it matches, print matched.

Example:

```
@array = ("R-ID 1.0001", "RA-ID 61.02154", "TCA-ID 49.021456","RCID 61.02154","RB-ID 61.02154");
@var = ("TCA-ID 49", "R-ID 1");

for (my $x = 0; $x <= 4; $x++)
{
  $array[$x] =~ /(.+?)\./;
  if( ($var[0] eq $1) or ($var[1] eq $1) )
  {
    print "\n deleted rows are :@array\n";
  }
  else
  {
    print "printed rows are : @array \n";
    push(@Matrix, \@array);
  }
```

Then I need to compare `@var` with the `@array`; if it is matched, print the matched pattern.

Here the entire logic is in a hireartical for loop which gives a new @array  in each iteration. so every time this logic is executed @array has different strings.

Then comes with @var it is user input field, this @var can be of any size. So in order to run the logic according to these constraints, I need to iterate the condition inside the if loop when the user input @var size is 3 for example.

So the goal is to match and delete the user input stings using the above mentioned logic. But unfortunately tis logic is not working. Could you please help me out in this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by `I am not able to compare it in if loop`?  Can you not use `for` or `while` to iterate through `@array`?

Comment: Hello @pmqs, I mean I can write a for loop and keep checking in the entire array, but when I have 2 strings in $var, then the logic is not working.

Comment: The purpose is if I have 2 strings in $var then it should compare and match the 2 strings, then the matched string should be printed out. I hope this explanation is sufficient. Thank You.

Comment: You have changed your requirements. Update the the main question to state what form `$var` takes. Is it only two strings you need to match or more?  Are the strings space/colon/tab delimited? Please specify exactly the format you are using.

Comment: Ok let me rephrase my question

Comment: Hello @pmqs, I hope in this new question, I have listed all my contraints to get better understanding of my problem.

Comment: Sorry, it still isn't clear what you are trying to do. Can you update the question to show a self-contained script that we can run (the current script has a syntax error). Show what you get when you run the script and most importantly show what you expect the output to be.

Answer (score 5):

The builtin `grep` keyword is a good place to start.

```perl
my $count = grep { $_ eq $var } @array;
```

This returns a count of items (`$_`) in the array which are equal (`eq`) to `$var`.

If you needed case-insensitive matching, you could use `lc` (or in Perl 5.16 or above, `fc`) to do that:

```perl
my $count = grep { lc($_) eq lc($var) } @array;
```

Now, a disadvantage to `grep` is that it is *counting* the matches. So after if finds the first match, it will keep on going until the end of the array. You don't seem to want that, but just want to know if any item in the array matches, in which case keeping on going might be slower than you need if it's a big array with thousands of elements.

So instead, use `any` from the List::Util module (which is bundled with Perl).

```perl
use List::Util qw( any );
my $matched = any { $_ eq $var } @array;
```

This will match as soon as it finds the first matching element, and skip searching the rest of the array.

Comment: The explation is good, but the main problem is I have 2 strings in $var and suppose I want to search it in an @array of size 6. If it matched it should print out the matched item. Thank you for your time to resolve this issue.

Comment: When I answered the question, `$var` was a single string. You have now changed it to `@var`, which changes the situation significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple of versions that allows multiple strings to be matched. Not clear what form `$var` takes when you want to store multiple, so assuming they are in an array `@var` for now.

The key point is this one is the use of the `lookup` hash to to the matching.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @var   = ("TCA-ID 49", "RA-ID 61");
my @array = ("R-ID 1", "RA-ID 61", "TCA-ID 49");

# create a lookup for the strings to match
my %lookup = map { $_ => 1} @var ;

for my $entry (@array)
{
    print "$entry\n" 
        if $lookup{$entry} ;
}
```

running gives

```
RA-ID 61
TCA-ID 49
```

Next, using a regular expression to do the matching

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @var   = ("TCA-ID 49", "RA-ID 61");
my @array = ("R-ID 1", "RA-ID 61", "TCA-ID 49");

my $re = join "|", map { quotemeta } @var;

print "$_\n" for grep { /^($re)$/ } @array ;
```

output is the same